# I am trying to make a method that works like the splice method but that works on objects

Tags: javascript, object, splice

Here is the constructor function, an 'push' function and an 'add' function.

```
function Erray() {
    this.storage = {};
    this.index = 0;
  }
  
  Erray.prototype.push = function(value) {
    this.storage[this.index++] = value;
  }

Erray.prototype.add = function(index, value) {
    for (let i = index; i <= this.storage.length; i++) {
      if (i === index) {
        break;
      }
      this.storage[i] = this.storage[i - 1];
    }
    this.storage[index] = value;
  }
```

The problem comes when I try to call the add method.

```
let array = new Erray;
  array.push(1)
  array.push(2)
  array.push(3)
  array.add(1,1)
```

I keep getting "arrray.add is not a function". Could you please tell me why? Thank you for your time!

Comment: do you mean [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)?

Comment: I'm not getting any error: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-shaw-qy28c?file=/src/index.js

Comment: `arrray.add` is spelt wrong. Did you mean `array.add` (with two Rs)

Comment: I'm in Visual Studio... what do you mean delete?

Comment: @DaShaman `delete` is a (little known) JavaScript keyword that allows you to delete properties from objects.

Comment: @DaShaman Is that your _actual_ code? I just tested it, and it seems to work just fine?